# MCMC chain getting stuck

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, hierarchical-bayesian, gibbs, metropolis-hastings

I am trying to use a Metropolis-within-Gibbs type algorithm to sample $\theta$ and $x$ from the following model.  Starting with Bayes theorem I can write:
$$
P(\theta, x | y) = \frac{P(y | x, \theta) P(\theta)}{P(y)}
$$
I can easily draw samples from $P(\theta)$ and $P(x | \theta)$, so I factor $P(y | x, \theta)$ into $P(y | x) P(x | \theta)$.

Bayes theorem again is now,
$$
P(\theta, x | y) = \frac{P(y | x) P(x | \theta) P(\theta)} {P(y)}
$$

- $P(y | x)$ is multivariate Gaussian.
- $P(x | \theta)$ is multivariate t.
- $P(\theta)$ is uniform.

**My sampling steps:**

1. Start with some value of $\theta$, say, $\theta_1$.
2. Gibbs step: Draw a sample $x_1$ from $P(x | \theta_1)$.
3. Plug my $x_1$ into $P(y | x)$ and evaluate (y was observed data).
4. Metropolis step: Accept $\theta$, $x_1$, if $P(y | x_1) > P(y | x_0)$.  If not, accept $\theta$, $x_1$ with probability $a = \frac{P(y | x_1)}{P(y | x_0)}$.
5. Go back to step 2, using $\theta_1$ if it was accepted, otherwise, draw a new $\theta$ from the proposal, then go back to step 2.

**The problem is that $\theta$ gets stuck.**  Sometimes I will get a draw of $x$ from $P(x | \theta)$, where that $x$ will be nearly identical to y, making result from $P(y | x)$ exceptionally high.  After that happens, essentially all my steps are rejected.  $a = \frac{P(y | x_1)}{P(y | x_0)}$ for pretty much all subsequent $\theta$ steps is a very small number.

**Here is why I think this happens:** The likelihood $P(y | x)$ is very sharply peaked.  On the other hand the distribution $P(x | \theta)$ is very broad in comparison.   When $\theta$ changes a small amount, $P(x | \theta)$ is essentially unchanged.

Would a different sampling strategy work better in such a situation?  Let me know if further info is required.

Comment: Have you tried different starting values for $\theta$?

Comment: The denominator in the Bayes theorem is $p(y)$, not $p(\theta)$

Comment: This can happen if you have large variation in your x-sampling; you get an unlikely value so that you never accept another proposal. If you do some kind of random walk proposals then you could try to adjust the variance.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the catch alberto and @Jens-Kouros.  Edited question regarding starting values of $\theta$

Comment: @Hunaphu, could you elaborate more?  Yes, I do have large variation in my x sampling.  What do you mean by 'do some random walk proposals' to try to adjust the variance?  It is what it is right?

Comment: Wait, no I don't see why my first equation is incorrect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In step 4, you don't have to reject the proposal $x,\theta$ every time its new likelihood is lower; if you do so, you are doing a sort of optimization instead of sampling from the posterior distribution.

Instead, if the proposal is worse then you still accept it with an acceptance probability $a$.

With pure Gibbs sampling, the general strategy to sample this would be:

**Gibbs**

Iteratively sample:
\begin{align}
p(x | \theta, y) &\propto p(y | x) p(x |\theta)\\
p(\theta | x, y) &\propto p(x | \theta) p(\theta)
\end{align}

**Gibbs with Metropolis steps for non-conjugate cases**:

If you some of the conditionals above is not a familar distribution (because you are multiplying non-conjugates; this is your case) you can sample with Metropolis Hastings:

- From the current $x$, generate some proposal, e.g.:
  $$
  x^* \sim \mathcal{N(x, \sigma)}
  $$
- Accept $x^*$ with probability [1]:
  $$
  a = min \left(1, \frac{p(x^*)}{p(x)}\right)
  = min \left(1, \frac{p(x^* | \theta, y)}{p(x | \theta, y)}\right)
  $$

[1] If the proposal distribution wasn't symmetric then there is another multiplying factor.

**Appendix:**
$$
p(\theta | x, y) = 
\frac{p(y|x)p(x| \theta)p(\theta)}
{\int p(y|x)p(x| \theta)p(\theta) \text{d}\theta}=
\frac{p(x| \theta)p(\theta)}
{\int p(x| \theta)p(\theta) \text{d}\theta}
\propto p(x| \theta)p(\theta)
$$

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the question.  I do what you suggest, in step 4, I refer to this as the "metropolis step ... etc".  I will edit the question to be more clear

Comment: How did you factor $P(\theta | x, y)$ into $P(x | \theta)P(\theta)$?

Comment: See the Appendix :)

Comment: Btw after your last edit I would say you are missing a factor in $a$. You consider that your proposal is symmetric, but it is not. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm

Comment: My proposal distribution for proposing values of $\theta$ is symmetric.  Does drawing from $P(x | \theta)$ change that?  One other small point.  In this, y is my "data", so I don't think I can sample $P(y | x)$ in $P(y | x)P(x | \theta)$.

Comment: If a multivariate t is symmetric then it's ok. You can always sample from whatever you want if you can evaluate $p(y|x)p(x |\theta)$ at individual points, since this is proportional to the posterior you want to sample from. You can always evaluate the second step of the M-H once you made no matter what new proposal: $p(y | x^*) p(x^* | \theta) / p(y | x) p(x | \theta)$

Comment: So my $a = p(y | x^*)p(x^* | \theta)/p(y | x)p(x | \theta)$, not $a = p(y | x^*)/p(y | x)$?

Comment: I was a bit confused by your sampling protocol but yes. Maybe this also helps (MH, Gibbs and  variable-at-a-time
Metropolis-Hastings or Metropolis-within-Gibbs) http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/701/S13/notes/2-28.pdf

Comment: See my last edit.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an R code in the univariate case for the above Metropolis-within-Gibbs approach drafted by @alberto. No indication of the chain getting stuck: the acceptance rate for the $x$ component is close to 50%.

First, I picked some pseudo-values to run the algorithm:

```
#observation from N(x,1)
y=3.081927
#latent x from t(nu,theta,1)
nu=3
```

Second, I simulated the location $\theta$ from the full condition distribution, namely a Student's $t$-distribution with location parameter $x$ and the latent parameter $x$ by a Metropolis-within-Gibbs step, making a proposal from a Student's $t$-distribution with location parameter $\theta$ and accepting this proposal based on the second part of the full conditional, namely the normal pdf centred in $y$.

```
#Metropolis-within-Gibbs
T=10^4
mcmc=matrix(NA,T,2)
#initialisation
mcmc[1,1]=rnorm(1,mean=y)
mcmc[1,2]=rt(1,df=nu)+mcmc[1,1]
#Gibbs iterations
for (t in 2:T){
   mcmc[t,1]=rt(1,df=nu)+mcmc[t-1,2] #theta
   mcmc[t,2]=proposal=rt(1,df=nu)+mcmc[t,1] #x
   #acceptance probability:
   accept=dnorm(proposal,mean=y)/dnorm(mcmc[t-1,2],mean=y)
   if (runif(1)>accept) mcmc[t,2]=mcmc[t-1,2]
   }
```

As seen from the contour plot below, the resulting chain $(\theta_t,x_t)$ is correctly located on the highest contours of the target density.

[image: representation of the log-posterior against a 10⁴ MCMC sample produced by the above code]

Comment: Cool plot!  But alas I feel more confused than when I started. Column 1 of your mcmc matrix is ... $\theta$, and column 2 is $x$?  The the sample from row 1 is added to row 2 and visa versa..?  Lost!  Thank you for your answer, I think it is my fault I am struggling to understand.